# Postgresql percentage of records created in the specific time interval

Tags: sql, postgresql, percentage

I have a table that contains the field `created_at`. I want to calculate the percentage of records from the total number that was created in the specified time interval. Let's say that I have the following structure:

```
| name   | created_at                   |
----------------------------------------
| first  | "2019-04-29 09:30:07.441717" |
| second | "2019-04-30 09:30:07.441717" |
| third  | "2019-04-28 09:30:07.441717" |
| fourth | "2019-04-27 09:30:07.441717" |
```

So I want to calculate what is the percentage of records created in the time interval between `2019-04-28 00:00:00` and `2019-04-30 00:00:00`. In this time interval, I have two records `first` and `third`, so the result should be `50%`. I came across the `OVER()` clause, but either I don't get how to use it, or it's not what I need.

Comment: I removed the `plpgsql` tag because it is only relevant if you write a stored function (or procedure) using `language plpgsql`. It is not relevant for "normal" SQL queries

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but I'm ok if the answer will include stored procedures using `plpgsql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use `avg()`:

```
select avg( (created_at between '2019-04-28' and '2019-04-30')::int )
 from your_table
```

You can multiply by 100, if you want a value between 0 and 1.

I strongly discourage you from using `between` with date/time values.  The time components may not behave the way you want.  You used "between" in your question, but I left it in.  However, I would suggest:

```
select avg( (created_at >= '2019-04-28' and 
             created_at < '2019-04-30'
            )::int
          )
 from your_table;
```

It is not clear if you want `< '2019-04-30'`, `<= '2019-04-30'` or `'2019-05-01'`.

Comment: This one looks pretty elegant. Will `avg()` work fine if I also use `where` clause in my query?

Comment: @SergiiBishyr . . . Yes.  The `where` filters the rows before the average is calculated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CASE

```
 select 100 * count(case 
      when created_at between '2019-04-28 00:00:00' and '2019-04-30 00:00:00' 
      then 1 
      end) / count(*)
 from your_table
```

Comment: Wow, it's much easier than what I have googled before. Thanks a lot!